# Benchmarking JVM memory consumption similarly to how it is done by the Android OS

Tags: java, memory, jvm, benchmarking, memory-profiling

When trying to benchmark a specific method, in regards to how many objects are created and how many bytes they occupy while that method is running, in Android it is possible to do this:

```
Debug.resetThreadAllocCount()
Debug.resetThreadAllocSize()
Debug.startAllocCounting()
benchmarkMethod()
Debug.stopAllocCounting()
var memoryAllocCount = Debug.getThreadAllocCount()
var memoryAllocSize = Debug.getThreadAllocSize()
```

I would now like to benchmark the same method, but on a normal desktop application, where these methods are not available. I have not found anything similar, and any other memory benchmarking code I have tried does not provide consistent results, like the above code does, which gives the exact same result every time when the same benchmark runs.

Any suggestion, preferably just code would be appreciated, however I would be open to try some software as well if it is able to perform the task I am trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ThreadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadAllocatedBytes(long)) can help:

```java
com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean bean =
        (com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean) ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
long currentThreadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();

long before = bean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(currentThreadId);
allocatingMethod();
long after = bean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(currentThreadId);

System.out.println("Allocated " + (after - before) + " bytes");
```

The method returns *an approximation* of the total allocated memory, but this approximation is usually quite precise.

Also, [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) has Java API for profiling allocations. It does not only count how many objects are allocated, but also shows the exact allocated objects with the stack traces of the allocation sites.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AsyncProfiler profiler = AsyncProfiler.getInstance();

    // Dry run to skip allocations caused by AsyncProfiler initialization
    profiler.start("alloc", 0);
    profiler.stop();

    // Real profiling session
    profiler.start("alloc", 0);

    allocatingMethod();

    profiler.stop();
    profiler.execute("file=alloc.svg");  // save the output to alloc.svg
}
```

How to run:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/async-profiler -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-UseTLAB Main
```

`-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-UseTLAB` options are needed to record *all* allocations. Otherwise, async-profiler will work in sampling mode, recording only a small portion of allocations.

Here is how the output will look like:

[image: Allocation graph by async-profiler]